# javascript radio button validate

Tags: javascript

hey guys i just try to do some validate for my javascript radio button, but is not work. every time i click submit button it just nothing happened.below is the code.

HTML part

```
   <form name="FirstPizza">
         <td>
             Style:
                <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="style"/>
            Thin Crust
                <br />
            <input type="radio" name="style" />
            Deep Dish
                <br />
            <input type="radio" name="style" />
            Sicilian
        </td>
   </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm(){
        if((!form.style[0].checked)  && (!form.style[1].checked) && (!form.style[2].checked))
             {
           window.alert("You must have a  style")
             }
```

i should come with a box but nothing happen. Do i miss something?

Comment: is `form` defined anywhere above this function scope?

Comment: no it doesn't, should i add something here?

Comment: that's your problem then.  `form` is undefined.  I'll provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close!  According to your comment, your `form` variable was not defined.  You need to define `form` somewhere like this:

```
function submitForm() {
  // define the form variable
  var form = document.getElementsByName("FirstPizza")[0];

  if((!form.style[0].checked)  && (!form.style[1].checked) && (!form.style[2].checked))  {
    window.alert("You must have a style");
  } else {
    window.alert("a style was selected");      
  }
}
```

*(see working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r8mv9m01/))*

Comment: keep in mind @OP, that you need to execute that function somewhere.  In my jsfiddle, for time's sake, i had just made a button.  You'd typically put this in something like `<form onsubmit="return submitForm()">` then your JavaScript would `return false` if there was a validation issue

Answer (score 1):

Use IDs for your form controls!  Try this:

HTML part

```
   <form name="FirstPizza">
         <td>
             Style:
                <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="rbThinCrust" name="style"/>
            Thin Crust
                <br />
            <input type="radio" id="rbDeepDish" name="style" />
            Deep Dish
                <br />
            <input type="radio" id="rbSicilian" name="style" />
            Sicilian
        </td>
   </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitForm(){
        if (!document.getElementById("rbThinCrust").checked && !document.getElementById("rbThinCrust").checked && !document.getElementById("rbThinCrust").checked)
           //Logic for nothing being checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both your HTML and JavaScript are completely broken.

First, your HTML.  You have no HTML for a button there, which you need should you wire your javascript event to it in the first place.

You would create a submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(this)" />
```

Your radio buttons also should have their text set via the `value` attribute, like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="style" value="Thin Crust" />
<input type="radio" name="style" value="Deep Dish" />
<input type="radio" name="style" value="Sicilian" />
```

Now your javascript, it should look something more like this:

```
function submitForm(form){
    if((!form.style[0].checked)  && (!form.style[1].checked) && (!form.style[2].checked))
    {
        window.alert("You must have a  style")
}
```

Hope that works for you.

And your end HTML should look like this:

```
<form name="FirstPizza">
Style:<br />
<input type="radio" name="style" value="Thin Crust" />Thin Crust<br />
<input type="radio" name="style" value="Deep Dish" />Deep Dish<br />
<input type="radio" name="style" value="Sicilian" />Sicilian
</form>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this person is just getting started with HTML / JavaScript.. take it easy on em! `:)`  one step at a time

Comment: @sircapsalot yeah sorry if I came across as harsh!  I'm terrible at getting the right point across sometimes.

Comment: In my years of programming and teaching new engineers, there really is a way to get points across.  too much "constructive feedback" like this could be detrimental to their development `:)`  SO is no exception.  There are definitely things that just make sense as you progress in your development career `:)`  those little picky rules like using ID's, is DEFINITELY part of that development.  No harm though. no worries.  Heck, i still have to remind SENIOR web developers to use ID's.  *sigh*